# Rails 3: rake:assets precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Whenever I run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
missing auth params or block
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Hard to know without more information. Try running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`, and it might give you the filename and line number that is causing the error.

Comment: Basically, the error has nothing to do with the precompilation. It's just loading the env, and it will fail if there are errors in your code base.